# C# byte array to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

**I want to convert string of array to byte array and vice-versa**

Eg.

```
string[] strArr= new string[]{"1","2","3"};
Byte[] byteArr= strArr.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray()
```

Now want to convert it back again to

```
string [] originalArr= ??? from Byte[]
```

I tried

```
strArr.Select(innerArray => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(innerArray)).ToList();
```

but not working

Comment: What do you mean by `not working` ?

Comment: Wow wow Mr. Faktorovich, it's not duplicating the question that you are referring.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate - OP wants to know how to convert an array of strings to an array of bytes & then convert the array of bytes back to a matching array of strings.

Comment: Getting error at this line byte[] bytes = strings.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();

Comment: Input string was not in correct format 
if my string is like  {"ProductCode":"PP211766","IsItem":"True","IsBPA":"True"}

Comment: Can the strings in your question also be Characters ? ore more than one number? If it is the answer from @Andrei is not right. If you use a number bigger than 255 it will trow an `argument out of range exception`. And if characters in the string array it will throw an `Input string was not in correct format`

Comment: If my string is like  this  
"{\"ProductCode\":\"PP202920\",\"IsItem\":\"True\",\"IsBPA\":\"False\"}"

Comment: @Pratik9975 it looks more like a JSON for me. Are you trying to deserialize JSON to an object?

Comment: I am in situation where i want to send NServiceBus message with data string array and this carries around 50000 elements in array but NServiceBus not allow to send message size greater that 4MB so i need to convert it into byte array as per nservicebus documentation. My array is like 
string[] arr= 
new string[]{"{\"ProductCode\":\"PP202920\",\"IsItem\":\"True\",\"IsBPA\"‌​:\"False\"}","{\"ProductCode\":\"PP202920\",\"IsItem\":\"True\",\"IsBPA\"‌​:\"False\"}","PP00001","123456"}

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "1","2","3" };
byte[] bytes = strings.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
strings = bytes.Select(byteValue => byteValue.ToString()).ToArray();
```

**Warning:** `byte.Parse` will throw runtime exception if string can't be converted to byte e.g. it's not a number of it's >255. Additional checks may be needed for correct execution. Check out `byte.TryParse` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f78h0es7(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

This is just one of the ways. You may also find `Convert` class very useful. It has many static methods to convert values to different types, including `Convert.ToByte(...)` or `Convert.ToString(...)`. Please see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.